# JS Plugin freezes browser for large calculation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using "Angular" htmldiff plugin to show difference between two HTML strings. issue occures when the data is very large.

```
htmldiff(oldData, newData);
```

this line freezes my browser for a long time.

I used Promise to make it work but it still creates the same issue.

here is my promise function

```
function p () {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
              debugger;
              var content = htmldiff($scope.leftPanel.fileContent, $scope.rightPanel.fileContent);
              resolve(content);
            });
          }
```

here is how I'm using it

```
p().then(function (content) {
                $scope.rightPanel.fileContent = content;
                $scope.leftPanel.fileContent = content;
              });
```

Comment: consider swapping to AngularJS promise with `$q` service

Comment: It doesn't matter, the lib is synchronous. Even if you wrap it inside promise it will still be synchronous. Consider making the same thing in your server and have client to call it with ajax.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey same issue with $q.

Comment: @alex-rokabilis will give it a try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Computation-Heavy Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299715/angularjs-computation-heavy-tasks)

Comment: I assume it's `htmldiff` function freezing up the browser. Have you considered making the function a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)?